# Batch File to Compare Properties Files [beginner]

Tags: batch-file, compare

I writing a Batch file to compare the properties of two or more files.

The files I will be comparing all have the same format shown below:
property1=prop1
property2=prop2
...

For my output, I would only like the lines with differences to be displayed. I tried using the FC command, but it seems to include the lines prior to and after the line with the difference as well.

Is there a way to just display the lines with differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`FC.EXE`](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html), use the [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bdc20eac-bff6-44bc-b130-1a986c79fb78(v=wps.630).aspx) from  `powershell.exe`:

> *Detailed Description*
>
> The `Compare-Object` cmdlet compares two sets of objects: one set of
>   objects is the "*reference set*", and the other set is the
>   "*difference set*".
>
> The result of the comparison indicates whether a property value
>   appeared
>
> - only in the object from the reference set (indicated by the `<=` symbol),
> - only in the object from the difference set (indicated by the `=>` symbol) or,
> - if the `IncludeEqual` parameter is specified, in both objects (indicated by the `==` symbol).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem change next two `set` commands to meet your circumstances: 
set "_refFile=%temp%\ReferenceFile.txt"
set "_difFile=%temp%\DiferenceFile.txt"

powershell -command Compare-Object ^
  -ReferenceObject  $(Get-Content "%_refFile%") ^
  -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content "%_difFile%") ^| Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Too *formidable*? Just use (from an open `cmd` window):

```
powershell -c compare (type file1.txt) (type file2.txt) ^| FT -auto
```

or even:

```
powershell -c diff (gc file1.txt) (gc file2.txt)
```

**Note**:

> The [`Get-Content` cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=290491) gets the content of the item at the
>   location specified by the path, such as the text in a file. It reads
>   the content one line at a time and returns a collection of objects ,
>   each of which represents a line of content.
>
> The [`Format-Table` cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293962) formats the output of a command as a
>   table with the selected properties of the object in each column. The
>   object type determines the default layout and properties that are
>   displayed in each column, but you can use the `Property` parameter to
>   select the properties that you want to see.

Comment: I used `powershell -c compare (gc file1.txt) (gc file2.txt) ^| FT -auto` How can I get rid of the SideIndicator column? Also, what does the `-c` command do?

Comment: And is it possible to get rid of the "InputObject" text above all my properties?

Comment: @Alan Please read link to the _`Format-Table` cmdlet_ (given in my answer already). Pay your attention to parameters `-HideTableHeaders` and `-Property`. Then you could use `… ^| FT -Auto -Hide -Property InputObject`. For `-c` meaning, see `-command` parameter description in `powershell /?`.